# simulate click button after opening webpage

Tags: c#, webrequest

I have a requirement where I open a webpage using

```
WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(uri);
```

This webpage has a download button which needs to be clicked to download a zip file to my local directory. I do not know the URL for this download button, if i mouse over it it just shows the .aspx address.

Now how can I simulate this click so I can download the file?

Comment: Is the URL unique?  Why not just navigate to that url and download the file once a week (much easier than a button press simulation)

Comment: We want to automate this process because we are planning to do many such downloads

Comment: Have you considered parsing html page from `WebRequest` to get target url from this button? You Can also do UI automation from C# Code Using for example WatiN

Comment: If the page you're trying to scrape needs to run in a web browser, then you could use the WebBrowser control to automate it.

Comment: @user2726975 you could still automate it.  What I am trying to say is what is the point of having your script emulate the button click, when you can just have a scheduled event download the zip at the specified URL?  If the URL contains no unique elements (ie no generated identifiers) then you can just navigate to the url in code and download its file.

Comment: @maccettura, I do not know the URL for download to happen automatically. I just know the page that has the button.

Comment: You could probably extract that information from the source.  Look into this way because if the URL is standard you will have a much easier and cleaner solution.

Comment: You might just ask the owners of the page for the URL. Or ask them if there's a better way to download what you need. There's no need to hack around in that case.

Comment: @maccettura, I don't know how to extract that info from source

Comment: @john saunders, it's a government website

Comment: It's a government website, so you can't ask them, or what?

Comment: Can you link us to the website?  Or is it private?

Comment: @maccettura, https://wyobiz.wy.gov/Business/Database.aspx I want to simulate clicking download btn.

Comment: `webBrowser1.Navigate(@"<url>");`
//when document load complete you can do any form filling or //submiting things like this,but you must used web browser object on //your code
`webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("textbox1").InnerText = "12345";`            `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit1").InvokeMember("click");`

Comment: @Elshan, how do I do this. Should I create a new Web form and add it to the project..can you please explain

Comment: think.if you want to automate facebook login page.you load the page to browser.then used firebug or chrome inspect element tool to find input buttons or textbox id's.then you can emulate any event via the c#,i'll send you sample.

Comment: if your question got write answer tag it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SampleBrowserautomate
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // first of all, insert web browser control and button control into your form
        string target = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(target);
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser b = (WebBrowser)sender;
            b.Document.GetElementById("email").InnerText = "helloworld@gmail.com";
            b.Document.GetElementById("pass").InnerText = "HelloWorld";
            b.Document.GetElementById("u_0_1").InvokeMember("click");
        }
    }
}
```

Another examples on msdn

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.setattribute(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.setattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What about UI automation? Is this what you're after?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx

EDIT: How about Web UI automation?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404082.aspx

Comment: ,no.I need the zip file every week and we want to automate that using c#. The webpage download button needs to be clicked automatically from my c# program for it to download . How can I do this??

Answer (score 0):

So I am working on this in between things, but check this out.

You can fire the client side event of that button using this javascript:

```
__doPostBack('DownloadButton','OnClick');
```

This will work with the 'javascript:' header in the chrome console.  Now you could probably automate this using greasemonkey(firefox) or another add on for chrome.